# How can I take the seven days before a date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date

How can I take the seven days before a date in Oracle SQL?

The query is

```
SELECT
  *
FROM log
WHERE action = 'KA'
AND REPOMOD
```

`REPOMOD` is a field Date

Comment: 'REPOMOD is a field Date' does that mean Repomod is a field of date type?

Comment: Try `select * from tablename
where yourdatecolumn between sysdate-7 and sysdate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from log where action = 'KA' 
And REPOMOD >= sysdate -7
```